# A question about  open subsets of Hilbert space

Tags: gn.general-topology

If H is (a separable and infinite dimensional) Hilbert space and if U is a non-empty
open subset of H that is not connected, does the boundary B of U always have at least
one component that is not a singleton?

Comment: Just a few questions:

Why do you put so strict hypothesis (i.e. separability and Hilbert)? What about the finite-dimesional case (dim>1)? What about Banach spaces? And if we remove completeness?

Comment: Evidently, I was thinking of a real vector space.. Are you interested in complex Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Michele, every Banach space is homeomorphic to a Hilbert space, and every complex Hilbert space is homeomorphic (actually real-linear homeomorphic to) a real Hilbert space. 

Comment: Can't you simplify the question to does every connected (bounded) subset of a Hilbert space have boundary consisting of more than one point. 

Comment: @Bill Johnson: I didn't know that result.  Can you give a reference?

Answer (score 3):

Clearly it is true in the plane.

If $\dim >2$,
choose a plane such that its intersection with U is not connected and use the above statement.

Comment: Thanks, Anton, for showing how one could go about proving that my
question has a "yes" answer when restricted to a finite dimensional
Euclidean space having dimension not less than 2. This answer follows from the fact that closed and totally disconnected subsets of such Euclidean spaces are zero dimensional. I asked my question
about Hilbert space because (1) I do not know if it has been answered in this case (2)Hilbert space is closest to Euclidean spaces and homeomorphic to separable Banach spaces as Bill Johnson
has pointed out.

Comment: I did not assume that $\dim<\infty$.

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: Applying your strategy to Hilbert space, suppose
That P denotes the plane in H which we choose to intersect with U.
This intersection will be an open subset ,V, of P. Then we need to
prove (1)We can always choose P so that, if U is not connected then
V is not connected. (2) the boundary ,F, of V is a subset of the
boundary ,B, of U. When we consider the humunguously complicated
shapes that open subsets of Hilbert space (such as U) can have, I
wonder how difficult it might be to actually prove (1) and (2).

Comment: My mistake! It is not at all difficult to prove (1) and (2), so
your method works for the infinite-dimensional case as well. Bravo.
